# Embedding an Excel attachment in Evernote

Tags: microsoft-excel, evernote

I'm looking for a practical way to share an Excel sheet with my spouse through Evernote, so that we can both consult and modify it.

I know that you can simply attach an Excel sheet in an Evernote note, and as long as you open and modify the note on the same machine, that works as expected.

However, when she opens the Excel on another PC, it simply opens up to a local folder and all modifications are only saved to this local copy and not to the actual note within Evernote.

Is there any way, short of dropping the attachment and re-attaching it every time, to get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe Evernote was designed to do real-time collaboration with attachments and/or spreadsheets, so I would have to say no to your question.

There are a few free options you can consider:

- **[GOOGLE DRIVE/SPREADSHEETS](http://drive.google.com)**. Upload the spreadsheet to Google docs & convert it to a Google spreadsheet. You and your spouse can then work on the spreadsheet even at the same time. Excel and Google Spreadsheets have similar functions (though syntax may be different).
- **[DROPBOX](http://dropbox.com/)**. You'll both need to install the app, have sync turned on and save the spreadsheet in Dropbox's local folder. Dropbox will take care of syncing or keeping both your copies updated with the most recent changes.
- **[EXCEL WEB APP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/web-apps-help/introduction-to-excel-web-app-HA010378338.aspx)**. This requires a Microsoft Skydrive or Live account (free).

Comment: While you have good suggestions, the question isn't about real-time collaboration. @Sam just seems to be looking for something similar to uploading new versions in Sharepoint. I only have Evernote on one desktop, however, so I'm not sure what this behavior looks like.

Comment: @Dane So far, at least with Evernote, you're going to have to drop/reattach the file every time you want to make changes.

Comment: All three of these are perfect answers. Dropbox will give OP the most consistent experience (i.e., they can use the exact same program they are already using).